# Atualizar um site para uma versão mais recente do Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Como é feita a atualização de um site desenvolvido em Ruby on Rails para uma versão mais recente do Rails?

Por exemplo do 4.2.4 para um possível Rails 5.0.0.

Ainda sou iniciante na linguagem e no framework e fiquei com essa dúvida de se por exemplo eu desenvolver em uma versão vou precisar ficar preso na versão.

Comment: Em termos gerais a maioria das atualizações vai precisar de zero ou quase nenhuma modificação no seu código, mas é bom testar tudo antes de subir uma atualização para produção. Fora isso, é tão simples quanto um `gem update`.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado. Achei precisaria editar cada arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente sempre que vem uma nova versão do *Framework* eles colocar no *guides* oficial deles !

Qualquer duvida e só acessar o link [GuidesRubyOnRails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)

Espero ter ajudado.